# How to Access AEM Log Files Using the SSH Access to AEM 6.5

Tags: adobe, aem

I'm trying to access logs files via Adobe Managed Services - AEM 6.5 using SSH credentials provided. However, I don't have any idea how to get the logs since I used getting the logs through the local project folders that I have. Any link or comment suggestions would be a great help for this one.

Comment: Are you trying to see the logs either Author or Publish? Each has different paths.